# Can't deploy plain Intellij Java EE project with selected frameworks support to Wildfly server

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

I am trying to setup this Java web application project with the following frameworks(libraries). I selected thos when creating new project in Intellij IDEA.
web application (3.1)
JSF (2.2.1)
    Primefaces (6.1)
EJB (3.2)
Hibernate (5.2.10)
JavaEE Application (7)
JavaEE Persistence (2.0)

I haven't changed anything, i only tried to start it so i could get going, but it can't deploy, bunch of errors appear.

I will put information from log i think are important, because i can't put whole log in post.

```
13:52:04,031 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Bookstore.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.BookstoreDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore.war#BookstorePU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.BookstoreDS]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore.war#BookstorePU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.BookstoreDS]"
    ]
}
13:52:04,328 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 11377ms - Started 433
13:52:08,181 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.workWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(XMLHelper.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
13:52:08,181 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.workWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(XMLHelper.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
13:52:08,188 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"
    },
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\"",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\""
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
13:52:08,189 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"
    },
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\"",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\""
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."ejb.jar".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldStartService, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 3 more ] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".CdiValidatorFactoryService, service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.deployment.unit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 6 more ] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear"."web.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.session (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BookstoreWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
[2017-09-15 01:52:08,303] Artifact Bookstore:ear exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-09-15 01:52:08,306] Artifact Bookstore:ear exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory","jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/web.war#BookstorePU\"","jboss.persistenceunit.\"Bookstore_ear_exploded.ear/ejb.jar#BookstorePU\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
13:52:09,161 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Bookstore.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Bookstore.war.dodeploy
```

Comment: It looks like you're including a dom4j library in your deployment. You'll want to make sure you're not including that in your deployment.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dom4j library from Hibernate was making problems, after excluding that from deployment everything deployed successfully.